# Create a function that reads a single line from a file when called. When looped, return x lines

Tags: c

I am currently studying c programming and I have an assignment called get_next_line.

This is my function prototype:

```
int     get_next_line(const int fd, char **line);
```

This is what it's supposed to do according to the assignment:

```
"Write a function that returns a line read from a file descriptor."

"What we call a “line” is a succession of characters that end with ’\n’` (ascii code 0x0a) or with End Of File (EOF)."

"Calling your function get_next_line in a loop will then allow you to read the text available on a file descriptor one line at a time until the end of the text, no matter the size of either the text or one of its lines."
```

The way I understand it, if your function is called once, you return a single line. If your function is called within a loop, you return x lines. Note that the prototype has no argument that indicates how many times the function has been looped. So my problem is, how will my function know to read x lines or just a single line?

The test file contains 3 lines of 5 zeros. 
I have tried using 2 while loops to read all the lines in the file, but testing my function with a loop will be pointless then no? Because instead of returning x lines it will return all the lines x times.

I have tried searching Google. I have spent countless hours trying to figure this out. But I'm stuck and in need of some help! I am not sure if I'm missing something obvious as is usually the case.

A few things though, we are only allowed to use while loops. We are only allowed to use read, malloc and free. Only 5 functions are allowed per c file and 25 lines per function. For this assignment only 1 c file is allowed. We aren't allowed to use printf, but I use it for testing. We may use a custom made library consisting of re-made functions such as:

```
memchr, putstr, strjoin, strsplit, memcmp, putstr_fd, strlcat, strstr, atoi, memcpy, strcat, strlen, bzero, memdel, strchr, strmap, isalnum, memmove, strclr, strmapi, isalpha, memset, strcmp, strncat, isascii, putchar, strcpy, strncmp, isdigit, strdel, strncpy, strnequ, isprint, putendl, strdup, strnew, itoa, strequ, strnstr, toupper, memalloc, putnbr, striter, tolower, memccpy, striteri, strrchr, strtrim, strsub.
```

So, below is my code. If anyone can give me guidance I'd appreciate it.

```
static void     ft_doread(const int fd, char **line, char *buff, int x, int y)
{
    if (buff[y] != '\n')
    {
        read(fd, (void *)buff, BUFF_SIZE);
        line[x][y] = buff[y];
        y++;
    }
}

int             get_next_line(const int fd, char **line)
{
    int     x;
    int     y;
    char    *buff;

    buff = (char *)malloc(BUFF_SIZE);
    x = 0;
    y = 0;
    ft_doread(fd, line, buff, x, y);
    return (0);
}

int             main(void)
{
    char    *str;
    int     fd;
    int     lines;

    str = (char *)malloc(BUFF_SIZE);
    fd = open("./test.txt", O_RDONLY);
    get_next_line(fd, &str);
    printf("%s", str);
    return (0);
}
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a homework assignment with absurd requirements and limitations.

Comment: Code has 3 casts.  None of them are needed.

Comment: The code isn't perfect yet, I know. It's a work in progress with bits and pieces of peer suggestions :) But I believe Scott Hunter gave me the information I needed to solve my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it meant that the call within each iteration of the loop will return a successive line, so that if called X times from within a loop, it will yield X lines *one at a time*.  As such, the function only needs to keep track of where it is in the file (which you will unless you forcibly change the position or close and re-open the file).